# CanHub Image Cropper stuck when cropping

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, image-cropper

I am using CanHub image cropper in Jetpack Compose like this:

```
val profilePictureCropLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    CropImageContract()
) { result ->
    if (result.isSuccessful) {
        profilePicturePath = result.uriContent!!
    } else {
        val exception = result.error
    }
}

val profilePictureSelectorLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
) { uri ->
    profilePictureCropLauncher.launch(
        CropImageContractOptions(
            uri,
            CropImageOptions(
                fixAspectRatio = true,
                outputCompressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG
            )
        )
    )
} 
...
...
profilePictureSelectorLauncher.launch("image/*")
```

Where I first select an image from gallery/camera, then pass it to the CanHub cropping activity. However, in the crop activity, there is no button to confirm the crop.

[image]

Is there some code I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem: I set my default AppTheme to a custom one that didn't have an action bar, I just had to explicitly declare CropImageActivity with a theme that had one, like Theme.AppCompat.